# How do i get my code to loop through all attributes of an object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, object

I just learned python and i'm trying to see what is possible.
When i made this testscript the code gave an error.

```
class test():
    list = {}
    value = 0
    def __init__(self, *args) -> None:
        y = 0
        self.value = test.value
        test.list[self.value] = []
        for x in args:
            self.x = y
            y += 1
            test.list[self.value].append(x)
        test.value +=1
        print (test.list[self.value])
        for i in test.list[self.value]: print (self.i)

a = test("a", "b", "c", "d")
```

This code should output:
`["a", "b", "c", "d"]`

```
0
1
2
3
```

But instead i get an error saying "AttributeError 'test' object has no attribute 'i'".
How do i get the code to go trough all the attributes of a and output it's value.

Comment: First off, you are shadowing the standard class `list`, which is likely to cause problems - you should never use the name of a built-in as a variable name. Second, you don't define an attribute `self.i`, which is where the error is coming up. Also, you are defining `list` as a dictionary, not a list. To define a list, use either `[]` or `list()`.

Comment: i changed all the words "list" to "objects" but nothing has changed

Comment: i just found out that it defines self.x instead of self.a or self.b
so i have 2 problems now

Comment: I think there may be some confusion as to the purpose of classes and objects, as it isn't clear to me why you are printing out the contents of `test.value` (a class member variable) in the constructor. What sort of data objects is this class meant to represent?

Comment: The instance variables (e.g., `self.value`) are properties of the object being created, and are defined as part of the class. I am not aware of any way in Python to add a new instance variable name at run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the error occur here:

```
for i in test.list[self.value]: print (self.i)
```

should be:

```
for i in test.list[self.value]: print (i)
```

UPDATE

In this example you get both Numbers first and then the letters:

```
class test():
    def __init__(self, *args) -> None:
        my_list = []
        value = 0
        y = 0
        value = 0
        for x in args:
            my_list.append(x)
            print(y)
            y += 1
        print (my_list)
        for i in my_list: print (i)

a = test("a", "b", "c", "d")
```

Comment: i don't get an error anymore but now i get the letters instead of the numbers

Comment: i want it to output 1, 2, 3, 4

Comment: You can use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate), thusly: `for i,v in enumerate(test.objects[self.value]): print (i)`.